# Wordpress menu_icon, how to get images from child-theme (/images folder)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the code below to add images to my custom post type admin roll, however I'd like to have my images loaded from my /images folder on my child-theme.
Any idea?

```
// Define icon style for the custom post type
function casestudy_icons() {
?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #menu-posts-parceria .wp-menu-image { background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/casestudy-icon.png) no-repeat 6px -32px !important;
    }
    #menu-posts-parceria:hover .wp-menu-image, #menu-posts-casestudy.wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-image {
    background-position:6px 0px !important;
    }
    #icon-edit.icon32-posts-parceria {background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/casestudy-32x32.png) no-repeat;}
</style>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'casestudy_icons' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered your custom post type via register_post_type then you should just use the 'menu_icon' parameter.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type